# Pairwise comparison for interaction effect using Repeated Measures Mancova

Tags: spss, multiple-comparisons, mancova

I am using a Repeated Measures Mancova with 4 factors, each one with 8 groups.  I also included 3 covariates in the analysis.  I discovered there was a significant difference between at least two groups in one of my interactions.

I would like to apply a Pairwise comparison to compare separately the groups of my factors, but taking into consideration the interaction. How can I do that in SPSS?

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, sorry. But don't try this. This approach was a reasonable idea in 1980, it's not a good idea any more. If you're into this sort of thing, here's a podcast: https://quantitudepod.org/s2e09-manova-must-die/

Comment: Close-voters: I believe this question is primarily about *statistics*, not *programming*, and that it should therefore stay open. See [Closing "software questions".](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5985/1352)